# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'as_matrix'

Tags: anaconda, python-3.7

I am getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'as_matrix'

The code that produces the error:

```
def plot_fruit_knn(X, y, n_neighbors, weights):
    X_mat = X[['height', 'width']].as_matrix()
    y_mat = y.as_matrix()
```

Can anyone help me spot the problem?

Comment: as_matrix is deprecated.

Comment: As @N.Kiefer states, the problem you are most likely running into here is copying an old example that uses (by now) deprecated methods. Your current version does no longer contain the method you are trying to use. Try to find a more up to date guide on what you are trying to accomplish, or (not recommended) use the same versions as your example.

Answer (score 0):

as_matrix() is depreceated you can use Dataframe.to_numpy() instead

```
y_mat = y.to_numpy()
```

Comment: .to_numpy() and .values()

Comment: What are you trying to convert ```X[['height', 'width']]``` into?

Comment: LINE 172 AND 173 GIVE ERROR OF BELOW CODE

Comment: https://ifxhwvazvvdsfiyigelncm.coursera-apps.org/edit/adspy_shared_utilities.py

Comment: Sorry no one can access your coursera notebook. If you want help include the code in the question.

Comment: Now the above link for the  Code is accessible . Please provide the solution if you can?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I used .to_numpy()

Use

```
y_mat = y.to_numpy()
```

instead